# Removing every instance of a key from Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain what on earth I'm doing wrong here:

I have the following code:

```
    console.log(table);
$.each(datatableFields, function (a, b) {
    if ($.inArray(b.substring(0, 3), neededFields) == -1) {
        console.log('deleting ' + b);
        delete table[b];
    }
});
console.log(table);
```

What I'm trying to achieve should be simple:

I have a Javascript Object which I want to 'strip down' and remove any unnecessary fields.

The 'neededFields' array simple contains a list of fields that I wish to keep, anything not in that array is removed from the master Object.

Running the code above, I can confirm the logic works, and sure enough Firebug shows me "deleting ###" perfectly for any fields in the master Object and NOT in the 'neededFields'.

BUT...

It doesn't appear as if my 'delete table[b]' command works as intended as both 'console.log(table)' return the same results!

Any thoughts?

As an example if I have the following Object:

> {ABC:123, CDE:456, FGH:789, IJK:012, LMN:345},
>
> {ABC:123, CDE:456, FGH:789, IJK:012, LMN:345},
>
> {ABC:123, CDE:456, FGH:789, IJK:012, LMN:345},
>
> {ABC:123, CDE:456, FGH:789, IJK:012, LMN:345},
>
> {ABC:123, CDE:456, FGH:789, IJK:012, LMN:345},
>
> {ABC:123, CDE:456, FGH:789, IJK:012, LMN:345},
>
> {ABC:123, CDE:456, FGH:789, IJK:012, LMN:345}
>   (etc......)

And removing certain keys (say IJK and ABC), my end result would be:

> {CDE:456, FGH:789, LMN:345},
>
> {CDE:456, FGH:789, LMN:345},
>
> {CDE:456, FGH:789, LMN:345},
>
> {CDE:456, FGH:789, LMN:345},
>
> {CDE:456, FGH:789, LMN:345},
>
> {CDE:456, FGH:789, LMN:345},
>
> {CDE:456, FGH:789, LMN:345}
>   (etc......)

*edit*

"datatableFields" is an array that contains all the keys within the master object, likewise 'neededFields' is an array that contains keys which need to be kept.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you do $.each(table, function(){}) what contains datatableFields

Comment: Because that would go through the entire object (which can be quite big) and I'm trying to optimise the function be going across rather than down.

Comment: datatableFields is an associative array?

Comment: No, datatableFields is a simple array which, in my above example, would contain {ABC,CDE,FGH,IJK,LMN}.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your following line:

```
delete table[b];
```

for this one:

```
delete table[a];
```

because the index of the element is on the first parameter of the `$.each` callback, so it's the `a` parameter in your example, while `b` contains the value, see [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for details.

Comment: Thanks, but that unfortunately doesn't work.  This now deletes 'objects' rather than the individual 'keys' from the entire object.

Comment: Try to provide a testcase on http://tinker.io so we can better reproduce your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Array.map for this

```
function neededFields( a_field ) {

  delete a_field["IJK]
  return a_field; 
}

datatableFields.map( neededFields );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aartiparikh/XaXeA/